# Difficulty read logcat to textview

Tags: android, android-studio, android-logcat

I have a Touch Mobile Computer with a barcode scanner.
I'm trying to write an application and I'm trying to build up an infrastructure for future errors.
So I want to build a screen that will show me the logcat after a malfunction occurred. In addition I try to extract the log to a text file inside the device and the internal storage of the device. To do this I created another activity to switch to another screen when I click the Log button - to display the log.

I would be happy to help with what I'm doing wrong.
In addition to how I can get the logcat to a text file inside the device and the internal storage of the device, when I tried to do this no txt file has been created in the device's internal folders.

```
public class LogActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView log;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_log);

    log = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.logTextView);
    log.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

    StringBuilder logBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            logBuilder.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    log.setText(logBuilder.toString());

} }
```

But when I click the Log button I get the following logcat when my app works perfectly and does not collapse:

> I/System.out: --------- beginning of crash
>   I/System.out: E/AndroidRuntime( 3708): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5
>   I/System.out: E/AndroidRuntime( 3708): Process: com.example.galchaplin.warehouseapplication, PID: 3708
>   I/System.out: E/AndroidRuntime( 3708): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
>   I/System.out: E/AndroidRuntime( 3708):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
>   I/System.out: E/AndroidRuntime( 3708):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
>   I/System.out: E/AndroidRuntime( 3708):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
>   I/System.out: E/AndroidRuntime( 3708):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>   I/System.out: E/AndroidRuntime( 3708):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>   I/System.out: E/AndroidRuntime( 3708):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>   I/System.out: E/AndroidRuntime( 3708):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>   I/System.out: E/AndroidRuntime( 3708):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>   I/System.out: E/AndroidRuntime( 3708): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "9D1801"
>   I/System.out: E/AndroidRuntime( 3708):  at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
>   I/System.out: E/AndroidRuntime( 3708):  at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:410)
>   I/System.out: E/AndroidRuntime( 3708):  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:367)
>   I/System.out: E/AndroidRuntime( 3708):  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
>   I/System.out: E/AndroidRuntime( 3708):  at com.example.galchaplin.warehouseapplication.MoveItemActivity$CheckLocation.doInBackground(MoveItemActivity.java:358)
>   I/System.out: E/AndroidRuntime( 3708):  at com.example.galchaplin.warehouseapplication.MoveItemActivity$CheckLocation.doInBackground(MoveItemActivity.java:347)
>   I/System.out: E/AndroidRuntime( 3708):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
>   I/System.out: E/AndroidRuntime( 3708):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>   I/System.out: E/AndroidRuntime( 3708):  ... 4 more
>   I/System.out: E/AndroidRuntime( 4228): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   I/System.out: E/AndroidRuntime( 4228): Process: com.example.galchaplin.warehouseapplication, PID: 4228
>   I/System.out: E/AndroidRuntime( 4228): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.galchaplin.warehouseapplication/com.example.galchaplin.warehouseapplication.MenuActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.CountDownTimer android.os.CountDownTimer.start()' on a null object reference
>   I/System.out: E/AndroidRuntime( 4228):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2986)
>   I/System.out: E/AndroidRuntime( 4228):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3017)
>   I/System.out: E/AndroidRuntime( 4228):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392)
>   I/System.out: E/AndroidRuntime( 4228):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
>   I/System.out: E/AndroidRuntime( 4228):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
>   I/System.out: E/AndroidRuntime( 4228):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   I/System.out: E/AndroidRuntime( 4228):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>   I/System.out: E/AndroidRuntime( 4228):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>   I/System.out: E/AndroidRuntime( 4228):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   I/System.out: E/AndroidRuntime( 4228):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>   I/System.out: E/AndroidRuntime( 4228):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>   I/System.out: E/AndroidRuntime( 4228):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
>   I/System.out: E/AndroidRuntime( 4228): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.CountDownTimer android.os.CountDownTimer.start()' on a null object reference
>   I/System.out: E/AndroidRuntime( 4228):  at com.example.galchaplin.warehouseapplication.MenuActivity.onResume(MenuActivity.java:112)
>   I/System.out: E/AndroidRuntime( 4228):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1257)
>   I/System.out: E/AndroidRuntime( 4228):  at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6119)
>   I/System.out: E/AndroidRuntime( 4228):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2975)

This code is located in the class where the button to the log screen is located.
In the class of the log code there is currently no countdowntimer.

[image]

Comment: show the code where you are using `CountDownTimer`

Comment: @Navneetヅ Hi, i added below the error the code of the ContDownTimer. is the timer has collision with the log code?